# I'm trying to do a data tag match on a potion, but it's not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.9, I'm making a one command thing, but I'm doing this command for a invisibility potion, and it won't work.

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] AStandCrafting 3 {OnGround:1b,Item:{id:"minecraft:potion",Damage:8206s,Count:1b}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potions no longer rely on the `Damage` value to determine the type of potion. Instead, a `Potion` string within the `tag` compound will state the name ID of the default potion. The wiki has a list of values [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Item_data).

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] AStandCrafting 3 {OnGround:1b,Item:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1b,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:invisibility"}}}
```